# File ended while scanning use of multicolumn

Tags: tables, errors, multicolumn, compilation-error

I am getting crazy with this code:

I get a "`File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn`".
This is one of multiple tables. They are all similar but I receive the error on this one (and the following) but not on the previous analogous tables.

I checked to the best of my abilities, and I think that the curly braces are all matched. Am I missing something or there may be another cause of the error?

This is the MWE

```
% This file was converted to LaTeX by Writer2LaTeX ver. 1.6.1
% see http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net for more info
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
% Page layout (geometry)
\setlength\voffset{-1in}
\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
\setlength\topmargin{2cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{2cm}
\setlength\textheight{17.001cm}
\setlength\textwidth{25.7cm}
\setlength\footskip{0.0cm}
\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength\headsep{0cm}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
  \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
  \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
  \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
  \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{2022-01-11}
\begin{document}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\pagestyle{Standard}

\bigskip







\bigskip

\begin{flushleft}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{}
\tabletail{}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{supertabular}{|m{3.698cm}|m{7.349cm}|m{6.9160004cm}m{6.7660003cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|m{25.328999cm}|}{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Studio: }}\textcolor{black}{Froylich D
}\textit{\textcolor{black}{et al. }}\textcolor{black}{Laparoscopic versus open ventral hernia repair in obese patients:
a long-term follow-up. Surg Endosc 2016}}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio}


\textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
\textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
\multicolumn{1}{m{6.9160004cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
\textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Disegno dello studio:}}\textcolor{black}{ Osservazionale}

~

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Certezze delle prove:}}\textcolor{black}{ Bassa}

~
 &
\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Paesi: }}Israele

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Centri:}}\textit{\textcolor{black}{ }}Singolo centro

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Setting:}}\textit{\textcolor{black}{ }}1 centro ospedaliero

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Finanziamenti}}\textcolor{black}{: Non riportati}

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Tassi di dropout:}}\textcolor{black}{ 6\% nel gruppo laparoscopico e 17\% nel gruppo open}

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Limitations:}}

\textcolor{black}{{}- Alti tassi di dropout al follow-up}

\textcolor{black}{{}- Diverse tecniche chirurgiche impegate}

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Critical appraisal:}}\textcolor{black}{ Newcastle-Ottawa} &
\multicolumn{1}{m{6.9160004cm}|}{Pazienti con ernia ventrale incisionale e primaria operati tra il 2004 e il 2012 (186
pazienti con obesità)

~

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Criteri di inclusione: }}\textcolor{black}{BMI {\textgreater}30
kg/m}\textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{2}}

~

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Criteri di esclusione: }}\textcolor{black}{Interventi in urgenza}} &
\textcolor{black}{Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. a cielo aperto}\\\hline
\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Note}}\textcolor{black}{:} &
\multicolumn{3}{m{21.431cm}|}{\textcolor{black}{Dimensioni del difetto (cm2)}

\begin{table}
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{|m{5.2770004cm}|m{5.275cm}|m{5.275cm}|m{5.2720003cm}|}

\hline
~
 &
\textcolor{black}{Open} &
\textcolor{black}{Laparoscopico} &
\textcolor{black}{P=}\\\hline
\textcolor{black}{Piccolo ({\textless}16 cm}\textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{2}}\textcolor{black}{)} &
\textcolor{black}{30.0\%} &
\textcolor{black}{14.2\%} &
\textcolor{black}{0.03}\\\hline
\textcolor{black}{Medio (16--64 cm}\textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{2 }}\textcolor{black}{)} &
\textcolor{black}{39.7\%} &
\textcolor{black}{40.0\%} &
\textcolor{black}{0.07}\\\hline
\textcolor{black}{Grande ( {\textgreater}64 \ cm}\textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{2}}\textcolor{black}{)} &
\textcolor{black}{28.4\%} &
\textcolor{black}{51.0\%} &
\textcolor{black}{0.02}\\\hline\end{tabular}

\end{table}
~
%}\\\hline
\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Outcomes}} &
{}- Recidiva erniaria (all'esame clinico e TC)

\textcolor{black}{{}- Complicanze}

{}-\textcolor{black}{ Infezioni di ferita}

\textcolor{black}{{}- Durata dell'ospedalizzaione in giorni}

~

~
 &
\multicolumn{2}{m{13.882001cm}|}{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Risultati: }}\textcolor{black}{186 pazienti con obesità (35
nel gruppo laparoscopico, 151 nel gruppo open.}

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{{}- Recidive:}}\textcolor{black}{ 27.1\% (Open) vs. 20.0\% (Laparoscopico); P=0.28}

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{{}- Morbilità:}}\textcolor{black}{ 20.5\% (Open) \ vs. 17.1\% (Laparoscopico); P=0.53}

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{{}- Infezioni di ferita:}}\textcolor{black}{ 15.8\% (Open) vs 5.7\% (Laparoscopico); P=0.09}

\textbf{\textcolor{black}{{}- Durata dell'ospedalizzazione in giorni:}}\textcolor{black}{ 3.8 {\textpm} 2.73 vs. 3.2
{\textpm} 1.75; P=0.234}}\\\hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you try to place a `table` environment inside of your `supertabular`?

Comment: The code is the output of the Libreoffice extension to convert a writer file into LaTeX. I was working to clean the code but I incurred in that error

Comment: Also, the closing bracket corresponding to the `\multicolumn` command starting in line 115 is commented out (see line 142).

Comment: Since a `table` is a floating environment, you can'r place it inside of a `supertabular`(or any other tabular-like environment). Remove the `table` envirnonment and just stick with the `tabular`.

Comment: In order to clean up the code, you may want to remove all occurences of `\textcolor{black}` as they are redundant here.

Comment: the`table` is wrong but the error is much simpler than that and accurately reported by TeX: you have an open brace here `{\textcolor{black}{Dimensioni del difetto` that you never close.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am under the impression that my TeXstudio editor does not report the full errors: I did not receive that indication from it.

Comment: from what I can tell from issues raised here and elsewhere, texstudio's summary of the errors is more or less useless, always look at the log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error reported by TeX is

```
Runaway argument?
{\textcolor {black}{Dimensioni del difetto (cm2)} \par \begin {table}\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> bb717
         
?
```

because the `{` before the (unnecessary) `\textcolor{black}` is never closed.

More exactly it would have been closed had this line not been commented out

```
%}\\\hline
```

If that `}` is restored that error will go but you will then get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

from the `table` environment which can not be nested in a `supertabular`.